# Django ModelForm ValueError

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

I have a Django Model

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

and ModelForm

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
   file = forms.FileField()
   category = mpttform.TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1))
   class Meta:
         model = UploadedFile
```

However, I'm having problem with this category field in UploadForm which is supposed to be Category instance (as definied in Model), but my queryset return list of Category objects which I use in template to show all leaf categories.If I select any category on the form and submit it, I get this error(in case I select cat5) 'Cannot assign [Category: cat5]: "UploadedFile.category" must be a "Category" instance.'
So I understand why this error is happening, but I'd like to use ModelForm because of save() method, but don't see how I can fix this.Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a little more info.If I set widget=forms.SelectMultiple for category i get  ValueError, but with widget=forms.Select works ok, but that widget isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Django is telling you that you must initiate a category instance in order to iterate over the categories. So the category instance takes params from the url,  url params with regex in your urls.py . So you need to capture the param and make it the category instance in the view.

*See class based generic views for which views automatically give you the params context variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
category = mpttform.TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1))
```

Works for a m2m relation and I guess category is a ForeignKey in the model Uploaded File. If so, you should use

```
category = mpttform.TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1))
```

Comment: yeah it will work, but will render that field as a ugly select widget, with TreeNodeMultipleChoiceField I get normal listbox and tha's what i want.When I set widget=forms.SelectMultiple for TreeNodeChoiceField I again get the same error as it was with TreeNodeMultipleChoiceFiel.